# Vue project on AWS S3 returns 405

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, axios, http-status-code-405

I am integrating a payment gateway in my vue project. Everything works well on my local server. But getting 405 error after deploying it to S3 on axios POST.

```
 const headers = {
    Authorization: "Bearer ...........",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
    "Set-Cookie": "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None"
  };

  const body = {
    amount: "119.0",
    .......
    ......
  };

  axios
    .post("/v2/charges", body, { headers })
    .then(response => console.log(response));
}
```

I have added proxy in vue config.

```
devServer: {
  proxy: 'https://api.tap.company/',
}
```

Error:

```
chunk-vendors.39b30f6f.js:7 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 405
    at t.exports (chunk-vendors.39b30f6f.js:7)
    at t.exports (chunk-vendors.39b30f6f.js:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest.h.onreadystatechange (chunk-vendors.39b30f6f.js:57)
```

Comment: For Proxy you are using devServer which will work locally, but when you build and deploy devServer will not be considered. Please check

Comment: How can I achieve this on a project hosted on s3 ?

Comment: To test, just put the complete url of your API in post like `.post("https://api.tap.company/v2/charges", body, { headers })`

Comment: I tried it. It shows CORS error

Comment: You can find solutions here on how to handle CORS error. I won't be able to give more details right now as it is very late here